# How to track the source of Custom Object updates?

Tags: custom-object, logging, history-tracking, debug

I'm facing many parasite `update` subscription API events for `Key_Feature__c` object.

Some of them are happening on the records that describe the activities finished in deep past. These records do not change, but still generate the `update` events. I know some ids of them.

My hypothesis is that some automation calls `update keyFeature` without changing any fields.

It might be anything - a flow or an Apex class. Unfortunately the org has hundreds of places where we save the `Key_Feature__c`. And lots of valid processes currently running.

How can I identify the automation pieces those are performing unnecessary saves?

What kind of tracking may I turn on or implement by myself?

Comment: Check the Modified By details - this will at least confirm that the records are being updated and show the contextual user against which the "no-op" update is being performed. Other than turning on debug logging and looking for database update messages and apex/flow execution tracing I can't think of a way to find where this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this occurring in a sandbox as well as production? It would be a lot easier to take additional steps in a sandbox to detect the unwanted updates. These could also be applied in production, but are more likely to have unwanted side effects.

You say that `Key_Feature__c` records shouldn't change. Especially the older ones. I'd use that as a basis for finding the problem processes.

In a sandbox you could create automation to prevent updates to older `Key_Feature__c` records. This might be an Apex trigger, a flow, a validation rule, etc... You want to check how old the record being updated is. If it is past the threshold, say a day old, then throw and error or otherwise prevent the transaction from completing.

E.g. with a trigger

```
trigger PreventUpdatesToOldKeyFeatures on Key_Feature__c (before update) {

    for(Key_Feature__c kf : Trigger.new) {
        if(kf.CreatedDate.addDays(1) > Date.today()) {
            kf.addError('Attempt to update old Key Feature');
        }
    }

}
```

Of course, a trigger may seem like overkill here. A Validation rule could be equally effective.

You might also want to check if there are any updates occurring to records with a master-detail relationship to Key Features.